# Unable to capture request responses of metro apps - proxy configuration

Tags: java, windows, windows-8, microsoft-metro, fiddler

I am new to using Fiddler and I have a windows 8 metro application to be tested. I want to use fiddler to see the requests and responses from that application. I have configured fiddler by running AppContainer Loopback Exemption Utility and checking the box against my app name. Also I have unchecked all use a proxy server for my LAN (but fiddler some how checks it though) ....... Anyways I was able to see the requests sent by IE and desktop apps, but unable to see the requests of metro apps ...... Please tell me how to solve this issue

Answer (score -1):

How is "java", which you tagged in your question, involved here? Metro apps are not written in Java.

Fiddler works by acting as the system's proxy. If you manually change the system's proxy configuration, Fiddler will not capture anything.

You should follow the steps described here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/httpfiddler/SsZnGxdxklg to get information which can help resolve your issue.